# Price-box.js overriding via Mixin bug - Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2

Overriding `'Magento_Catalog/js/price-box'` via mixin works in only Chrome and I can't understand why. Other jQuery widgets overriding works fine (breadcrumb, swatch-renderer)

$path-to-theme / **requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
  config: {
    mixins: {
      'Magento_Catalog/js/price-box': {
        'Magento_Catalog/js/custompricebox': true
      },
    }
  }
};
```

$path-to-theme / **Magento_Catalog/web/js/custompricebox.js**

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',
  'underscore',
  'mage/template',
  'jquery/ui'
], function ($, utils, _, mageTemplate) {
  'use strict';

  return function (priceBox) {
    return $.widget('mage.priceBox', priceBox, {
      _init: function () {
        this._super();
        console.log('Hello theme!');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

And it's works only in Chrome. Screenshots:

**Chrome:**

[image]

**Firefox:**

[image]

Comment: This should be fixed in the next release of Magento > 2.3.2 .. https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/24054

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should fix the filtering issue

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-role=priceBox][data-price-box=product-id-<?= $block->escapeHtml($_product->getId()) ?>]": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/price-box": {
                "priceConfig":  <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsonConfig() ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

See /app/code/Magento/Swatches/view/frontend/templates/product/listing/renderer.phtml

Comment: also check this file  Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/form.phtml here you have add same code if there is any old code of dataPriceBoxSelector = '[data-role=priceBox]'

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the price-box widget was called this way in the **module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/form.phtml**:

```
priceBoxes.priceBox({'priceConfig': <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsonConfig() ?>});
```

**in this script section:**

```
var dataPriceBoxSelector = '[data-role=priceBox]',
    dataProductIdSelector = '[data-product-id=<?= $block->escapeHtml($_product->getId()) ?>]',
    priceBoxes = $(dataPriceBoxSelector + dataProductIdSelector);

priceBoxes = priceBoxes.filter(function(index, elem){
    return !$(elem).find('.price-from').length;
});

priceBoxes.priceBox({'priceConfig': <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsonConfig() ?>});
```

If you override this template and call the priceBox widget this way, it works:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-role=priceBox]": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/price-box": {
                "priceConfig":  <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsonConfig() ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

With this way, you can't filter the price boxes.

Comment: THANK YOU. Still did not work with that selector, but with _.price-box_, it works. Did you ever found a proper solution ? I mean without rewriting anything but JS and not phtml ?